# mysqlcheck or check mysql table without marking the table as corrupted

Tags: mysql, percona

From percona documentation

> If CHECK TABLE encounters errors in InnoDB tables or indexes, it reports an error, and usually marks the index and sometimes marks the table as corrupted, preventing further use of the index or table. Such errors include an incorrect number of entries in a secondary index or incorrect links.

When I run this command, the table which has the index corruption becomes un-usable. Is there any way to find index corruption in mysql without actually marking the table as corrupted ?